# F#: Function parameter defaults to obj in class

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

I created a simple function:

```
let myGenericFunc abc = printfn "%A" abc
```

Its type is:

```
'a -> unit
```

Then I want to make it a member of a class:

```
type MyClass() =
    member x.Func = myGenericFunc
```

However, type of "Func" is now

```
obj -> unit
```

Moreover: If I make the parameter explicit, everything is ok again:

```
type MyClass() =
    // Func : 'a -> unit
    member x.Func y = myGenericFunc y
```

The question is: what happens ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first `x.Func` is defining a property, not a method and because properties cannot be generic it has to use a concrete type for `'a`.

When you define `x.Func y` you are creating a method and that can be generic.